# What is "a snack" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

A snack is a small meal eaten between regular meals. It could for example be some fruit or nuts or a small sandwich. What can I say in Esperanto?

Answer (score 11):

I usually use *manĝeto* (*manĝ-et-o* "tiny meal"), and it seems I'm not the only one: [https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manĝeto](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%C4%9Deto)